# Javascript submit on onchange, but do not refresh page

Tags: javascript, php, refresh, onchange

I have a `form` with a `<select>` and `<checkbox>`.
**I do not want submit button**, I want to use onchange on the form to "detect" the change and submit the data. I am processing the data with PHP, and I want a solution *that submits the data on onchange but do not refresh the page*.
I have read a lot of articles and Q&A-s, I tried AJAX, but I am not sure if is it possible to submit on onchange, without submit button and without page refresh.

**Edited:**
For the simplicity, let's say that a teacher teaches 2 grades. He wants to see all the names of each grades, but he also wants to filter the the students by result, which can be good or bad.

Code:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="student_form" onchange="showResult()">

<select name="students" id="students" >
<option value="" disabled>Select a garde</option>
<option value="all">Show all</option>
<option value="grade1">Grade 1</option>
<option value="grade2">Grade 2</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="result[]" value="good"<label>Good</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="result[]" value="bad"<label>Bad</label>

</form>
```

JS:

```
function showResult()
{

document.getElementById("student_form").submit();

}
```

Here I know it immediately refreshes, but I kinda lost in my own thoughts, so I do not know what to put inside the JS script that submits the data but does not refreshes the page.

I want to reach that each time the teacher selects either from the select or from the checkbox, it "updates" the results.

Comment: This is perfectly possible, and you seem to have all the building blocks required to do it. Post your code and explain what is not happening the way you want.

Comment: It is perfecty possible. You'll most likely end up getting the fields yourself however.

Comment: `I am not sure if is it possible to submit on onchange`...absolutely it is. And you can use AJAX if you like. What exactly is the problem? Did you try something which hasn't quite worked? It's unclear where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery with Ajax and select element using jQuery selectors and fire onChange event using jQuery and in that function, you can get the data of an element and pass that data by making ajax call

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can detect change at `<form />` level, but you can add `onchange()` event for each of your input (`<select>` or `<checkbox>`), something like:

```
<select onchange="validateData()" />
<checkbox onchange="validateData()" />
```

Then in `validateData()` function, you can call AJAX to submit manually your form.

PS: you can consider using `<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validateData()" />` . The `event.preventDefault()` will stop the page from reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, wrap it in an if statement, on change of the form, run your ajax and send back your values to the db.

```
   if ($('#form').change(function(){
    
    select = $('#select').val(); 
    checkbox = $('#checkbox').val();
    
    $.ajax({
        type:       "POST",
        url:        "YourUrl",
        dataType:   "html",
        data: {
            select: select,
            checkbox: checkbox
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            console.log('Test here');           
        }
        })
        .done(function(response){           
            console.log('Sent Data');           
        })
        .fail(function(response){

              alert( 'INTERNAL ERROR' );
                
            
        });
}else{
    console.log('Not working');
};
```

Comment: You might want to mention that this requires jQuery...